# "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable" sometimes appears, sometimes - not

Tags: python, recursion, stack-overflow

I have 2 functions for reading data from file and putting it to dictionary.

```
def read_input():
  f = open(r"D:\data.txt","r")
  g = {}
  for ln in f.readlines():
  ...g = ...
  f.close()
  return g
```

almost the same with the second function:

```
def reverse():
  f = open(r"D:\data.txt","r")
  g = {}
  for ln in f.readlines():
  ....
  f.close()
  return g
```

after that I had such code:

```
g = read_input()
g_rev = reverse()
```

works fine for small `g` & `g_rev` (for small input files). After that I need to do deep recursion so I added these lines and included both `read_input` and `reverse` to `main1`

```
if __name__=="__main__":
  sys.setrecursionlimit(100000)
  threading.stack_size(67108864*3)    
  thread = threading.Thread(target=main1)
  thread.start()
  thread.join(0)
```

still works fine wil small `g`... But with big input files I got such error:

```
g = reverse()
 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.
```

If I swap `read_input()` and `reverse()` and call `reverse()` it passed, but there is the same error for `read_input`

Comment: Does the `...` bit include `reverse = (something)` somewhere?

Comment: no, just reading data to init dictionary. Both functions are called just once

Comment: Why are you doing ``for ln in f.readlines():``? You can just do ``for ln in f:`` which iterates, rather than creating a list. More efficient.

Comment: You start out with "I have 2 functions for reading data from file and putting it to dictionary."  I don't see how that leads to threading and recursion.  Could you connect the dots for me?

Comment: What does this have to do with (a) Stack Overflow?

Comment: Stack Overflow - it was just suggestion, because for small input files everything works

Comment: "I don't see how that leads to threading and recursion" I got segmentation fault for big input files, so I tried this way... Regarding threading - the same, to increase stack size

Answer (score 0):

There might be a mistake with either the read_input() or reverse().
Scenario 1
By the time return g is executed, g is already a NoneType
Scenario 2
There's a defect with the functions that prevent them to reach the return g statement.

Either way, to really help you, we'll need more piece of your code especially the functions part.